# ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id

Tags: ios, network-programming, ios10, multipeer-connectivity, mpc

I have an App where users exchange data with IOS Multipeer Connectivity.

I liked Peter Fennema's approach for this and used his tutorial as a starting point, but getting many errors logged after the second iPad accepts the invitation to connect. See Peter Fennema's tutorial for the coding:
https://peterfennema.nl/ios-multipeer-2/

The connecting process does is done automatically, and thus no user acceptance required. I can't find any problem with the code, seems to be working fine,  just very annoying to see all these errors.

Would be grateful for any advice to get rid of them.

Apple bug maybe?

```
2019-05-28 14:14:03.747714+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2019-05-28 14:14:03.754876+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] PFViewController viewDidLoad
2019-05-28 14:14:03.772851+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] applicationDidBecomeActive
2019-05-28 14:14:03.772948+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] Peer iPad Air 2 is connecting
2019-05-28 14:14:03.796920+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] Browser iPad Air 2 found iPad on Macbook
2019-05-28 14:14:03.797003+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] Browser iPad Air 2 invites iPad on Macbook to connect
2019-05-28 14:14:05.844303+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] Advertiser iPad Air 2 received an invitation from iPad on Macbook
2019-05-28 14:14:05.844392+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] Advertiser iPad Air 2 accepted invitation from iPad on Macbook
2019-05-28 14:14:05.844525+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574902] iPad Air 2 received MCSessionStateConnecting for iPad on Macbook
2019-05-28 14:14:05.844949+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574904]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (199317133)
2019-05-28 14:14:05.854285+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574851] iPad Air 2 peers: (
)
2019-05-28 14:14:05.854287+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574902] iPad Air 2 peers: (
)
2019-05-28 14:14:06.988632+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:06.992184+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574902] iPad Air 2 received MCSessionStateConnected for iPad on Macbook
2019-05-28 14:14:06.992298+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574902] iPad Air 2 peers: (
    "iPad on Macbook"
)
2019-05-28 14:14:07.040019+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.075525+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.129766+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.220343+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.275756+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.449467+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.527873+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.876498+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:07.939371+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:08.599774+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:08.661743+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:09.840084+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:09.906472+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:11.377437+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:11.409906+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:12.896606+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:12.941097+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:14.444521+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:14.463490+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574947]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199     Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0000).
2019-05-28 14:14:15.877160+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [0BE1568D] on channel [0].
2019-05-28 14:14:15.886617+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [0BE1568D] on channel [1].
2019-05-28 14:14:15.894222+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (199317133)
2019-05-28 14:14:15.894964+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [0BE1568D] on channel [2].
2019-05-28 14:14:15.902320+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (199317133)
2019-05-28 14:14:15.903218+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [0BE1568D] on channel [3].
2019-05-28 14:14:15.910065+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (199317133)
2019-05-28 14:14:15.910802+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [0BE1568D] on channel [5].
2019-05-28 14:14:15.917513+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (199317133)
2019-05-28 14:14:16.474201+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [0BE1568D] on channel [6].
2019-05-28 14:14:16.482041+0800 MultipeerDemo[37709:1574910]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (199317133)
```

```
{
    NSLog(@"Advertiser %@ received an invitation from %@", self.peerId.displayName, peerID.displayName);
    invitationHandler(YES, self.session);
    NSLog(@"Advertiser %@ accepted invitation from %@", self.peerId.displayName, peerID.displayName);
    [self logPeers];
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I've seen a few posts about this error but I can't seem to figure it out.  I've been trying to connect between an iPhone and the simulator so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I wasted a lot of time debugging these errors, and it seems like they are not really errors meant for Multipeer Communication. I think these form part of Apple's logging and activity tracing and have chosen to ignore them. My App is working perfectly, but this is nonetheless annoying!

Comment: That's good to hear... I guess.  I was able to finally make a connection but had to disable security.